# ESM importing all files from folder with index.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

Consider this very simple project: [esm-test](https://github.com/mrjdavidfg/esm-test)

Runs on **Node.js v13**.

This project has `"type":"module"` in his `package.json` so Node.js will treat by default all files `.js` as ECMAScript modules. See: [ECMAScript Modules - Enabling](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

It has the following very simple structure:

```
- package.json
- src/
  - stuff/
    - a.js
    - b.js
    - index.js
  - app.js
```

The file `app.js` is the package entry point.

My purpose is to import all files from `stuff/` folder using the `index.js` file. I know that in ES6, having an `index.js` file in a folder lets you perform an import from the folder implicitly without specifying the `index.js` in the import statement.

So I can do:

```js
import { a, b } from './stuff'
```

Instead of:

```js
import a from './stuff/a.js'
import b from './stuff/b.js'
```

But it's not working for me. It shows the following error:

```
internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:96
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module C:\projects\esm-test\src\stuff imported from C:\projects\esm-test\src\app.js
    at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:96:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:72:33)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:156:40)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

With CommonJS modules works. But I want to do it with ESM.

Can you help me with this please.

Comment: Do you see @Vivek's answer? If it solves your problem, accept his answer. I see his answer. It's a perfect answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import `index.js` automatically in ESM is an experimental feature in the current version in  ode.js. You can use flag `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` while starting server.

E.g. `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index`

Please refer [this link](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_resolver_algorithm) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this work with "type":"module", you need to import including filename and extension i.e. "index.js", it won't look for index.js by default, other files also need to include the extension i.e. a.js

a.js / b.js

```
class a {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayName() {
    console.log('Hi, my name is ', this.name + '.');
  }
}

export default a;
```

./stuff/index.js

```
import a from './a.js';
import b from './b.js';

export {
    a,
    b
};

//Or "export default" depending on your needs.

export default {
    a,
    b
};
```

app.js

```
import { a, b } from './stuff/index.js'
```

If you have multiple named exports, you need to import like this.

```
import * as a from './a.js';
```