# Is it possible to retrieve all imported objects in ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, requirejs, amd

With RequireJS, you can do something like:

```
define(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(a, b, c) { 
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar for an ES6 module? Ex:

```
import a from 'a.js';
import b from 'b.js';
import c from 'c.js';

console.log(imported_objects); // should console log the values of a, b, and c
```

I'm asking because I'm working on a project that transforms AMD code to ES6 modules. When I do the transform, `arguments` is undefined because we're no longer inside of a function, but I need to be able to do something similar in ES6. I'm guessing this isn't possible because these are static imports? Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that I'm talking about [define](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) in the context of loading modules with RequireJS()

Comment: which environment we are talking about? bundler like webpack(I think there _might_ be some plugin) or native environment? and separately - what is the purpose? maybe there is workaround to reach the same goal in different way.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556130/esm-importing-all-files-from-folder-with-index-js-not-working help?

Answer (score -1):

Just write

```
console.log([a, b, c]);
```

There is no meta way to get this list from the environment. You can however easily generate it yourself by looking at the list of imports, especially when writing an automated code transform.